# Renaming sub package names in my Android project

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface, rename, eclipse-cdt

I have an Android project called my.android.project, and in my src directory, I have a few sub-packages called my.android.projectGUI, my.android.projectClasses, my.android.projectOthers.

I wish to change my package name to com.android.project instead. I have successfully done this  with Android Tools->Rename Application Package. However, this didn't take care of my sub packages in my src directory. I wish to rename them to com.android.project.gui, com.android.project.classes, and com.android.project.others

In my.android.projectOthers, I have a java file AccessJNI.java that loads a JNI library that is linked to jni/myjnifiles/myjni.c

When I try to change the sub-packages individually via Refactor->Rename, it works for the all except for my.android.projectOthers. Once I rename this sub-package, Eclipse throws me an error for several JNI symbols, saying they could not be resolved. This happens despite me changing all JNI function calls in myjni.c from Java_my_android_projectOthers_AccessJNI_functionName() to Java_com_android_project.others_AccessJNI_functionName()

The strange thing is, ndk-build still builds the library correctly, but Eclipse cannot seem to resolve the JNI symbols.

Am I missing anything while renaming my sub-packages?

Thanks!

Comment: How does the error message look? I have never seen Eclipse trying to match JNI method names.

Answer (score 0):

> This happens despite me changing all JNI function calls in myjni.c from `Java_my_android_projectOthers_AccessJNI_functionName()` to `Java_com_android_project.others_AccessJNI_functionName()`

You should replace all JNI prefixes by `Java_com_android_project_others_` and not `Java_com_android_project.others_`

Comment: that was a typo, I actually used _, not .

Comment: Ok, sorry then. Removing my post, it's useless! You should probably fix the typo ;)